# Conditional Grouping in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, string, group-by, sum

This should be easy, but I'm having trouble with it.

I have a `results` table that looks like this:

```
store_id    cust_id    spend_ind    pct
200         2          A            0.33
200         2          B            0.33
200         3          A            0.33
300         1          A            0.50
300         100        B            0.50
400         2          A            0.33
400         2          B            0.33
400         5          B            0.33
```

Notice that the `pct` column sums to 1.0 for each store.
Here's the code to create this table:

```
CREATE TABLE results(
    store_id int,
    cust_id int,
    spend_ind char,
    pct float
    );

INSERT INTO results VALUES(200,2,'A',0.33);
INSERT INTO results VALUES(200,2,'B',0.33);
INSERT INTO results VALUES(200,3,'A',0.33);
INSERT INTO results VALUES(300,1,'A',0.50);
INSERT INTO results VALUES(300,100,'B',0.50);
INSERT INTO results VALUES(400,2,'A',0.33);
INSERT INTO results VALUES(400,2,'B',0.33);
INSERT INTO results VALUES(400,5,'B',0.33);
```

I'm trying to group the results by store, then by cust_id while creating a new category `A&B` if the same cust_id has both `A` and `B` spend indicators for a specific store. Here's what I'm trying to output:

```
store_id   spend_ind   pct
200         A&B          0.66
200         A            0.33
300         A            0.50
300         B            0.50
400         A&B          0.66
400         B            0.33
```

For example, customer 2 has spending patterns `A` and `B` for store 200, so we create a new category `A&B` that sums the `pct` column for any customer with spending patterns `A` and `B`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would phrase this as:

```
select
    store_id,
    cust_id,
    group_concat(spend_ind order by spend_ind separator '&') spend_ind,
    sum(pct) pct
from results
group by store_id, cust_id
```

You possibly want another level of aggregation to group customers by their new category:

```
select store_id, spend_ind, sum(pct) pct
from (
    select
        store_id,
        cust_id,
        group_concat(spend_ind order by spend_ind separator '&') spend_ind,
        sum(pct) pct
    from results
    group by store_id, cust_id
) t
group by store_id, spend_ind
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bf33cd3bbcf4dd15d0198b09defc36c3)**

```
store_id | spend_ind |  pct
-------: | :-------- | ---:
     200 | A&B       | 0.66
     200 | A         | 0.33
     300 | A         | 0.50
     300 | B         | 0.50
     400 | A&B       | 0.66
     400 | B         | 0.33
```